# Solving a system of linear ODES without the eigenvector method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So this problem came up on a exam I had recently so forgive me that I do not have the actual numbers and what not. Basically, we had to solve a system of linear ODEs but not using the eigenvector method.

Let me clarify. We first formed a system of linear ODEs say of $x$ and $y$. We were suddenly told that let $u=2x+y$ or something like that and from there we could actually express $u'$ in terms of $u$. This is because we had expressions for $x'$ and $y'$ from the system of ODEs we had before. Similarly, we were given that $v=2x-y$ and we could also express $v'$ in terms of just $v$. We then had equations for $v$ and $u$. With this, we could find expressions for $x$ and $y$.

I thought this was really cool but why did this work? How does this relate to the eigenvector method where we rewrite the system of ODEs in matrix form and then finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix. Surely there has to be a connection?

Comment: where can i find your System?

Comment: This usually works because $(2,1)$ is a left eigenvector of the system matrix. But without seeing the system, one can not know for sure.

Comment: Why would this work if it is a left eigenvector?